# Can the new 'airforceone' tag be renamed?

Tags: support, tags

A recent [edit suggestion](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/33199) created a new tag: [airforceone](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airforceone).

I tried to improve the suggestion by using the dashes as they are the standard replacement for spaces, but I got this:

[image]

---

### Update:

A more [generic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_transports_of_heads_of_state_and_government) and thus of wider use tag [head-of-state-transport](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/head-of-state-transport) has been created.

Example of use is the pope flight question: [Is « Shepherd One » really used internationally by air traffic control for Pope's flight?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/47494/14897)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tonight (should be around 3:00 UTC) the system will automatically purge that tag, since it has no question attached to it. after that you'll be able to create the dashed version.

---

The undashed tag is now gone, you can now create the dashed version